# how to set security to allow anonymous users add ploneboard 3 conversation

Tags: security, plone

How to set security to allow  anonymous users add ploneboard 3 conversation?

I set "Ploneboard: Add Conversation" to anonymous users, but it doesn't work.

Comment: http://www.llakomy.com/articles/enable-kupu-for-anonymous-in-ploneboard

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the forum and change its workflow state from "Require membership to post" to "make free-for-all"